# Firebug 1.6 doesn't show me JS errors

Tags: jquery, firebug, script-debugging

I am working in local and I just updated firebug to the new version. Before the update whatever error that I was making with js, firebug was showing me on which line wasn't working the code (so I could understand where I did the mistake).

Now my website breaks, but I don't receive any message about JS not working from firebug. Is there something changed? 
Script is enabled.

this is the code

```
$("#cv").hover(
    // when the mouse enters the box do...
    function(){
        $("#hover-cv").css("z-index":"6");
        aniCircle(1, $(this), "#hover-cv", {scale:"1", "opacity":"0"}, {scale:"1.3", "opacity":"1"});
    },
    // when the mouse leaves the box do...
    function() {
        $("#hover-cv").css("z-index":"4");
        aniCircle(0, $(this), "#hover-cv", {scale:"1", "opacity":"0"});
    }
);
```

what is creating the error are the scripts "$("#hover-cv").css("z-index":"6");" and "$("#hover-cv").css("z-index":"4");"

I don't understand why Firebug doesn't warn me that something is wrong. More than the solution, I am worried about firebug not warning me on js errors.

Answer (score 0):

You either need a comma for the single [`.css(property, value)`](http://api.jquery.com/css/) version:

```
$("#hover-cv").css("z-index","6");
```

Or object notation (with the missing `{}`) for the property map version [`.css(props)`](http://api.jquery.com/css/):

```
$("#hover-cv").css({"z-index":"6"});
                   ^  missing    ^
```

I am seeing the same behavior in FireBug 1.6 as you not reporting this, can't find any mention of the bug in [the issues list](http://code.google.com/p/fbug/issues/list#) though.

Comment: Thx for the anser, I will rephrase the question, the problem is not my wrong JS, it is firebug that doesn't let me know where is the error

Comment: @Littlemad - you may be right, the syntax isn't quite valid here on the same line, (without the implicit new command), looks like it's a FireBug 1.6 error.

Comment: @Littlemad - After killing Firefox completely and testing it works, can still lock up at time though, seems like a bug in FireBug that locks up and needs a complete reload before it listens for errors properly again.

Comment: No I didn't report it, I wanted to be sure that I wasn't the only one to have this problem. Where is the place to report it? (In mainwhile I do reload to listen to error? just a refresh page?). I am switching back to 1.5.4 for the moment http://getfirebug.com/releases/firebug/1.5/ .

Comment: As Nick Craver already said, you can report Firebug bugs at http://code.google.com/p/fbug/issues/list. Include a complete test case and we'll fix it.

Comment: Nick I switched back to the old version, and $("#hover-cv").css({"z-index","4"}); throw me an error. So remove it from your answer. "{" "}" are not needed ;)

Comment: @Littlemad - Look closer :) it's either `{prop: name}` (notice the `:`) *or* with a comma.